# Rotate item: 90 degree rotations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found this script that lets you click on an item then drag to rotate it, but it rotates based on where your finger is, what can I do to rotate the object 90 degrees like you would in Tetris?

```
public class RotateDrag : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDrag(){
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
        float ang = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.forward);
    }
}
```

### Example

In photoshop when you want to rotate an item in a layer you can hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and it will snap to 45° angles as you rotate.

I however would like 90° angle snapping.

Comment: Do you want to discretly rotate in 90° steps or would you like a script that instantly rotates the `GameObject` by 90° in some axis? You should look at `Quaternion`, `transform.rotation` and `Quaternion.Euler()`. Simply put, you can do `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(new Vector(90f, 0f, 0f))` to additionally rotate an object by 90° in the x-axis.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you want the user to control the direction of the rotation, but the the angle?

Comment: What I would like is for it to rotate when the mouse moves to the top to rotate it up, when the mouse is below rotate it down, etc.

Comment: @ChrisF that sounds about right. They just will rotate around the object and it will snap to the proper rotation.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is just take the direction from the point selected, as the sign on the angle and apply that to a 90 degree rotation thus:

```
    float ang = 90.0 * Math.Sign(Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg);

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.forward);
```

Comment: That rotates the object once, and then it doesn't rotate again.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Ah. I see. Can you not add this rotation to the current transformation?

Comment: I tried this: `transform.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(ang, Vector3.forward);` but it just spins super fast without me doing anything.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn you need to extract the current rotation, add the new rotation and create a transform with that angle. I'm a bit rusty in this area though.